# How to find IP Address without asking the user to check it or remote connecting into the user's computer?

Tags: ip

How do you find the IP address of a user's computer (without asking the user to check it or remote connecting into the user's computer)?

Comment: So without having any physical or remote access, you want to find the IP address of a computer? What OS is the computer you want to use to find the IP and what OS is the computer you want the IP of?

Comment: Yeah,let me give a hint like If I run PING comand,how do I get IP?

Comment: So, Windows? OSX? On both computers?

Comment: I need it  for windows but want to know also OSX

Comment: Are they on the same network? I'd guess not because you said you don't want to 'remote connect' to it.

Comment: Yeah it will under same Network & remotely connected

Comment: if you know the hostname, nslookup will probably tell you. otherwise, I'd have the user type 'whats my ip' into google and read it back to you. you have to have some kind of identifier in order to determine the IP.

Comment: I have the Hostname,How Do I do that

Comment: Use an Advanced IP Scanner software and scan your network

Comment: if you have the hostname, you can just ping the hostname, and DNS will turn it into an ipaddress for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a smart phone connected to the same network try using "fing" it finds all devices on a network and there names. Or sometimes I log onto our router and check the list of connected devices and then ping them.